# Is there a way to pivot the last column name to be the last row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple query to sum all the numbers of rows in each table of a database. I want to pretty it up a little by having the last row be the name of the last column, total records and display the sum of all records.

```
select a.name
 ,b.rows, a.create_date
 ,a.modify_date
 ,sum(b.rows) over () as 
total_records
from sys.tables a
 inner join sys.partitions b on a.object_id = b.object_id
 where b.index_id = 1
 and b.rows > 1000
 group by a.name, b.rows, a.create_date, a.modify_date, b.rows
  order by b.rows desc
```

I tried a few variations of the above by including with rollup and a few other aggregate functions, but can't get it to look like I want to.

if it's possible i'd like something where the last row says Sum or Total or something in the Name column and the row column will have the value of the sum

Comment: can you clarify what do you mean with ´by having the last row be the name of the last column´ please?? right now i understand you want an extra-row summarizing the "total_records" results.

Comment: I'd like the last column I have, total_records to be in the last row returned under the a.name column and the sum of all rows to be in the last row of the b.rows column. I can do it when I export the data into excel, but was hoping if there is a way to do it in one step in SQL

Comment: there's no pretty way to do that... you'll have to execute the query twice and then put them together using an UNION, something like this: `WITH dummy_alias as ( SELECT ... your current query ), sums as (SELECT sum(d.total_records) s FROM dummy_alias d) select * from dummy_alias UNION ALL SELECT s, null, null, null, null FROM sums`. I'll not answer this question because this kind of it usually get downvotes.

Comment: thx, going to cheat with excel this time and see if I can automate it for the future

Answer (score 1):

UNION ALL your query with another query that selects the aggregations you want, and order by an artificial column that forces the second query to be the last row.

Comment: thx, going to cheat with excel this time and see if I can automate it for the future